# Application sill asking for login credentials after configuring Azure SSO

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have setup an onpremis saas application as a non-gallery app on Azure, and I have configured SSO.
When I browse to "https://myapps.microsoft.com/" and then select the application I onboarded, it still asks for login credentials.

From my signon logs, I could see this sample: Format urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress

value, god.ayang@silver.com

However,  I got this response from the app team: We do not use the email “god.ayang@silver.com” to access SOC. We use the Network ID “gayang”. The format is: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient

What can I configure in Azure SSO attribute/claims to reflect the networkID instead of email.

Answer (score 0):

> I have setup an onpremis saas application as a non-gallery app on Azure, and I have configured SSO. When I browse to "https://myapps.microsoft.com/" and then select the application I onboarded, it still asks for login credentials.

If still your application asking for login credentials, check the below points.

1. Verify that your application is properly configured for SSO.
2. Make sure that your application is set up to trust Azure AD
3. Confirm that the user is signed in with an account that has been provisioned in Azure AD
4. Verify that your application is properly registered in Azure AD

You can follow the below steps to configure **On-Prem Application** to **Azure AD** with **SSO**

1. I have installed an Application proxy connector on **Windows Server 2022**

**Azure Active Directory > Enterprise applications > Application proxy > Download Connector Service**

[image]

2. Once download the application, Install and log in with **Global Admin** user.
3. Verify the application proxy connector is installed and registred properly.

**Azure Active Directory > Enterprise applications > Application proxy**

[image]

4. Verify the application proxy connector is installed and registered correctly on your windows server.

[image]

5. Configure an application

**Azure Active Directory > Enterprise applications > Application proxy > Configure an app**

[image]

6. Configure single sign-on to the application as below.

**Open your application > Single sign-on > SAML**

[image]

7. Add the user to the application as below.

**Your application> Users and groups > Add user and groups**

[image]

8. Once complete all the configuration, the application will appear in [Apps portal](https://myapps.microsoft.com/).

[image]

9. If I launch the application from the apps portal, the application will be opening automatically without asking for credentials.

[image]

Refer: [Add an on-premises application for remote access through Application Proxy in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-add-on-premises-application)

[configure single sign-on to an Application Proxy application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-config-sso-how-to)

Comment: Thank you for your response but in this case, the app was added as a non-gallery image not with application proxy